# Margin:0px auto; is not working with Width:100%

Tags: html, css

`margin: 0px auto;` is not working with `width: 100%;` any one know the answer for this

```
Eg: .abc{
    margin: 0 auto 0px;
    width: 100%;

<div class="abc">
    <input class="acc" type="radio"  name="a">
    <label>hi.</label>

   <input class="cc" type="radio"  name="a">
   <label>No</label>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't center something with a width of `100%`, that doesn't make any sense. Reduce the width.

Comment: do you want to center something within a div with 100% width or the thing at 100% itself?

Comment: i want to make the content of the div center

Comment: @You-day Provide some code, and maybe an example demonstrating what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @You-day horizontally, vertically what?

Comment: @JoshC am sure he wants vertical

Comment: @Mr.Alien That may likely be the case. It's extremely unclear though.

Comment: @JoshC off to sleep anyways :D -You-day if you are looking for vertically center than look for `position: absolute;` or `vertical-align: middle;` with `display: table-cell;`, am sure Josh will help you if you make things clear a bit

Comment: @You-day Based on your update... http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/dNGU9/ .. is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 6):

100% width does not leave any space for margin.

`margin:0 auto` will work only on width less than 100%.

Write

```
{text-align:center}
```

to center content inside element.

[**Demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/5WTB6/1)

Comment: but if we are decreasing the width then its not possible to get the exact center

Comment: @You-day you want to center content inside element or want to center entire element?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are setting something as a full width you cannot centre it. The best option would be to set your width as either fixed width for example 'width:600px;' and then use 'margin:0px auto;' the other way would be to use a percentage width for example 'width:70%' and then also use 'margin:0px auto' this would mean that the styled element would grow or shrink to the screen size. With this option you can set the maximum size and the minimum size as well

Answer (score 0):

use  "text-align:center;" from the outer div

hope this helps